# Why does jsperf give different results based on preparation code in HTML vs setup?

Tags: javascript, html, parseint, parsefloat, jsperf

I was trying to see which methods of converting a string to a number in javascript are more performant, so I went to jsperf to see what might work best. However, I seem to be getting different results based on whether or not the initial variables are defined in the Benchmark.prototype.setup() function, or directly in the global scope.

[In the global scope](http://jsperf.com/parseintx1/15)

[In Benchmark.prototype.setup](http://jsperf.com/parseintx1/12)

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: A different scope may enable different interpreter optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because scope lookups come with a small performance penalty.

For example:

```
var foo = 42; // outer scope
(function() { // inner scope
  doSomething(foo); // needs to look up `foo` and fetch it from the outer scope
}());
```

Even if you ignore the overhead of the [IIFE](http://mths.be/iife) there, this is still definitely slower than:

```
var foo = 42;
doSomething(foo); // no scope lookups needed
```